# scanning an integer ONLY into an array

Tags: c, loops, scanf, do-while, digit

As a part of an assignment I've got, I need to get from a user a digit only using the `<stdio.h>` library.

```
do {
  scanf("%d",&num);
} while (num>9 || num<0);
```

But the program will get from the user also chars and other things.

Any advice?

Comment: Too unclear, please elaborate.

Comment: Read a line, convert the string in line to `int`? There are [functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) which can convert a number in a string to an integer, *with* validation of the string.

Comment: Do check for return value by scanf. If successful, the total number of characters written is returned by `scanf()`, otherwise a negative number is returned.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude those functions are not a part of stdio.h.

Comment: @PranavTotla No, `strtol` is not declared in `<stdio.h>`, it's declared in `<stdlib.h>` which is still a *standard* C header file. All C compilers should have it and the function.

Comment: @Dominique How could both `num>9` and `num<0` be true at the same time? If one is true then the other must be false, and using AND would make the whole combined condition false and break out of the loop, which is clearly wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of solving this is getting the ASCII value of the scanned "digit" and making sure it lies between ASCII values 0X30 and 0X39 (or 48 and 57).

Seeing your logic, you seem to be interested in numbers greater than 9 (multiple digit numbers) and numbers less than 0 (signed numbers/integers).

I suggest instead of using `scanf` better use something like `getchar` which will return one character at a time.

A simple way to scan multiple digit numbers using `getchar` can be:

```
int getNumber()
{
    int sign = 1;
    int i = 0;
    int ch;
    ch = getchar();
    if((ch == '-') || (ch == '+')) //check sign
    {
        if(ch == '-') sign = -1;
    }
    else  
    {
        if (ch > '9' || ch < '0')
            return NULL; // Your requirement - it's a non number
        i *= 10;
        i += ch - '0';
    }
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n') //get remaining chars
    {
        if (ch > '9' || ch < '0')
            return NULL; // Your requirement - it's a non number
        i *= 10;
        i += ch - '0';
    }
    i *= sign; //change sign
    return i;
}
```

You can call this function in place of `scanf`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getchar()` to read a single character from stdin and then compare it to the ASCII values for 0 and 9 (your upper and lower bounds for a single character). The digit as an integer is equal to the character code minus the character code for 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char c;

    while((c = getchar()) >= '0' && c <= '9')
        printf("Digit is: %d\n", c - '0');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `getchar()` typically returns 257 different values.  Saving that result as a `char` will lose information.  It _this case_, it likely makes little difference, yet `int c;` would be better.

Comment: @chux How can an 8-bit byte contain 257 different values? Don't you mean *256*?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `int getchar()` returns values in the `unsigned char` range  and `EOF`:  typically 257 different values.

Comment: On an related note about using `char` here, remember that [`getchar`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) returns a *`int`*. This is rather important if one wants to check for `EOF`.

Comment: @chux Okay, I see what you mean. But what if `char` is `signed`? ;)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude If `char` is `signed` or not does not affect the range of values returned by `getchar()`.  `getchar()` is somewhat mis-named as it is more like `get_unsigned_char()`

Comment: This point, although valid, would only change the output if the over/under -flowed value of EOF wraps within the range of 0-9, which is unlikely. A better example would use `int'.